# IOT Raspberry Pi 3 over no internet

Tags: router, raspberry-pi3, iot, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I've worked a tad with IOT on Raspberry pi before, but as a student I ran into a problem and was hoping someone could answer my question. So I need to run Windows IOT Core on the Raspberry Pi 3 (if it was up to me I'd use raspbian or some other flavor of linux, but it's not up to me) and I need to run it at a school who's network I don't have access to. Is there any way of running IOT on raspberry Pi without an internet connection. I had read somewhere that I could buy a router (and even though there was no internet connected to it) I could run ethernet from the router to my laptop and another from the router to the raspberry pi and ssh into the pi from my laptop. Is this true? and how would I go about ssh-ing into the pi? OR is there a better/alternative solution to running IOT with no internet?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly connect Raspberry Pi to your laptop with the network cable. Then the Raspberry Pi will get an IP address. With this IP address, you can either [debug app with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/remotedebugging) or [connect to the Raspberry Pi via SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/index). There are some tools like [IoT Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/iotdashboard) or [Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/deviceportal) you may need.

For more information about connecting Windows 10 IoT Core, you can reference [Windows 10 IoT documentation->Connect your device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/index).